# PDF.JS - convert Pixels to Points

Tags: javascript, pdf-generation, pdf.js

I am rendering a PDF on a webpage within a Canvas using PDF.JS

I am using my mouse to Drag Objects on my PDF, this way i can get the client's X (MouseX) position using javascript

```
var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
return e.clientX - rect.left
```

Above returns the result in pixels,

Now i am using a javascript Library (PDF.JS) to Render that shape within PDF. That library requires X position to be in "PDF Points" . All I have is the X position of my mouse within the rendered PDF in canvas. here is a sample to render object within PDF

```
const button = form.createTextField("ctrl_22");
button.addToPage( firstPage, {
    x: 200 // This needs to be in POINTS
  })
```

So is there a way i can capture the clientX of mouse and convert it into points?

Comment: I am taking the screen pixel then doing it * 0.24 (72/300) to get the pdf points. and seems like its working. what should I look for when using different displays? is 72 is a variable number for me which I would need to look for?

Comment: if i were to have a user provide me the information and then i can calculate the proper PPI? i am looking for a formula which i can pass parameters to and calculate the ppi. any recommendations?